# How to refactor .filter method on array so to pass one more variable needed for filtering?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Given an array with a list of participants, some students, some teachers :

```
var participants = [
    {'name': 'G01a','email':'g01a@m.io','group': '1','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'G01b','email':'g01b@m.io','group': '1','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'G02a','email':'g02a@m.io','group': '2','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'G02b','email':'g02b@m.io','group': '2','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'P01', 'email':'p01@m.io', 'group': 'teacher','role':'teacher'},
    {'name': 'P02', 'email':'p02@m.io', 'group': 'teacher','role':'teacher'},
];
```

I currently write 2 highly similar filter functions to filters students, then teacher:

```
// DERIVATED INITIAL DATA
var checkRoleS = function (participant){ 
  console.log(participant.role== 'student')
  return participant.role == 'student';
}
var students = participants.filter(checkRoleS);
console.log(students)

// DERIVATED INITIAL DATA
var checkRoleTeachers = function (participant){ 
  console.log(participant.role== 'teacher')
  return participant.role == 'teacher';
}
var teachers = participants.filter(checkRoleTeachers);
console.log(teachers)
```

**How to have a single `checkRole` function with one more parameter sot to pass forward the string "student" or "teacher" needed for the filtering ?**

Thus getting something like :

```
var students = participants.filter(checkRole("students"));
var teachers = participants.filter(checkRole("teachers"));
```

EDIT : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6k3uvxj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an anonymus function to call you check function with as many arguments as you want :

```js
var participants = [
    {'name': 'G01a','email':'g01a@m.io','group': '1','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'G01b','email':'g01b@m.io','group': '1','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'G02a','email':'g02a@m.io','group': '2','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'G02b','email':'g02b@m.io','group': '2','role':'student'},
    {'name': 'P01', 'email':'p01@m.io', 'group': 'teacher','role':'teacher'},
    {'name': 'P02', 'email':'p02@m.io', 'group': 'teacher','role':'teacher'},
];

var checkRole = function (participant, role){ 
  console.log(participant.role === role)
  return participant.role === role;
}

var students = participants.filter(i => checkRole(i, "student"));
console.log(students)

var teachers = participants.filter(i => checkRole(i, "teacher"));
console.log(teachers)
```

Comment: Thanks, I now use `var getAllByRole = function(participantsArray,role) { return participantsArray.filter(function (i) {  return i.role == role; }) };` derivated from your answer. See http://jsfiddle.net/a6k3uvxj/17/

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over `key` and value and return a function for getting an object.

```js
const
    filterBy = (key, value) => object => object[key] === value,
    participants = [{ name: 'G01a', email: 'g01a@m.io', group: '1', role: 'student' }, { name: 'G01b', email: 'g01b@m.io', group: '1', role: 'student' }, { name: 'G02a', email: 'g02a@m.io', group: '2', role: 'student' }, { name: 'G02b', email: 'g02b@m.io', group: '2', role: 'student' }, {  name: 'P01', email: 'p01@m.io', group: 'teacher', role: 'teacher' }, { name: 'P02', email: 'p02@m.io', group: 'teacher', role: 'teacher' }],
    students = participants.filter(filterBy('role', 'student')),
    teachers = participants.filter(filterBy('role', 'teacher'));

console.log(students);
console.log(teachers)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```